# Is it recommended to install other applications in SharePoint Servers Farm?

Tags: sharepoint-server

The management want to combine all the test applications inside one server to reduce the cost of test servers and test environments. So all stand alone applications such as ASP.NET web applications, ASP.NET Web services will be moved to the SharePoint Farm. Is it good practice to move them here and what are the implications? considering this is test environment.

Answer (score 0):

Which applications do you want to install in one SharePoint server?

If you want to install all applications in one test server, please make sure these applications have no conflicts with SharePoint. And also have enough CPU and RAM.